# Is there any way to show lines covered by unit tests on the editor view in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I am aware you can configure Idea to show the test coverage in a separate view, but is there any way to show the coverage in the main editor screen.

For example, I see the line numbers on the left, with a little green or red number in [] giving the number of unit tests run against this line.

Possibly something similar to the editor section (of Eclipse) shown here - http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/emma_eclipse2.png.

Is this possible? Is there a plugin to achieve this?

I'm using the IntelliJ coverage tool, and Idea 12.0.4 (build 129.549)

Thanks

Comment: Like this: [Integrated Code Coverage](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_coverage.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @maba linked to, you can turn this on in intellij.  [Here's a link from his link that gives much more thorough information about it.](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/07/code-coverage/)

[image: enable code coverage]

This is what it will look like when it's turned on:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I saw that afterwards, Doh! It's just that the default colours are hard to see and I missed them initially. I've now configured the colors to show on the editor as well as in the margin.